# Correlator vs product of function

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory

While reading about OPE of fields in Chapter 5 of di Francesco, I am confused about the meaning of some OPEs. Consider equation 5.83, which talks about the OPE of T with itself for a free boson
\begin{equation}
T(z)T(w) \sim \frac{1/2}{(z-w)^4} + \frac{2T(w)}{(z-w)^2} + \frac{\partial T(w)}{(z-w)}
\end{equation}
Here radial ordering is implicit. Is this equation only valid when we put correlation function on both sides or is it true as a product of operators as well ?

Comment: it is fine as an operator equation, but then you need infinitely many more terms (the regular terms).

Comment: An equation that is valid inside a correlation function with arbitrary additional insertions is equivalent to an operator equation.

Comment: What about other OPEs such as equation 5.77 of yellow book, \begin{equation} \partial \phi(z) \partial \phi(w) \sim - \frac{1}{4 \pi g}\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}\end{equation} I believe this is only true under correlation function.

Comment: as @AccidentalFourierTransform mentioned, these relations are all exact if you also include the non-singular terms on the rhs, which are in turn given by a Taylor expansion of the operator at z around w (because the singular terms have been removed). the latter expansion is just the normal-ordered version of the operator you started from on the lhs. Polchinski vol 1 explains the details.